# Security concerns in cookie exporting between browsers

Tags: facebook, cookies, identity, identityserver4, identityserver3

I'm posting a question which I posted [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/189325/security-concerns-in-cookie-exporting-between-browsers) again as I think this is the right place to ask this question

I'm wondering why Facebook is not handling the cookie export between browsers and related security concerns.This will be worst when they are using the "remember me" option as the cookies will be persisted for many days in the machine and someone can easily steam those cookies if it is a shared computer.

I think even Google is also not doing it. I copied the CURL from google with the cookies and executed it in the command line and I was able to get the expected outputs(mails). These 2 are used as identity providers in most cases. So I believe the applications which are using these two as the identity provider and using the remember me option which is provided by them also should face a similar threat.

Is there is an identity provider which handles it properly, maybe with the device fingerprinting or any other technologies?

Appreciate if someone could mention such IDPs and how it is handling that use case.

Comment: Try to run this curl request from different IP, maybe they are actually using network fingerprints. So, if someone stole your cookies, they would need to get your IP address and make request from it, which is quite hard to do.

Comment: Also, browsers usually encrypt all cookies, afaik, so it's really hard to get them without you knowing.

Comment: For the Facebook I have tried in a different machine. After getting the cookies I was able to login in other machine. I'm using my profile more than 3 weeks in other machine now after injecting those cookies. For google I will give a try.
Also, think about a scenario you steam the cookies itself from the same machine when someone logs in and going out for lunch without closing the computer. In such case cookie stealing is easy

Comment: Tested this with Google too. It works. Not restricting the cookie importing

Comment: well, that's how the web works :)
You can see the list of possible device fingerprints here, for example: https://amiunique.org/fp
And non of them are reliable enough, because if you will check user-agent, your user may update browser and UA will change. So, cookies are the gold standard, so far.